# how to assign static quality scores to selective documents based on specific criteria in lucene 3.5?

Tags: lucene

Suppose we want to give importance to documents that contain many movie-related words.For those documents,we want to assign some static quality score.For the subsequent queries, the scores are calculated as static score plus the score of the document against the query.

Answer (score 0):

Document boost is the feature designed yor such cases. Only, it is not additive, but multiplicative (it scales the raw score by the given factor), but this is probably what you need anyway.